# How can I display Title only in posts and no excerpts at all in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How can I display Title only in posts and no excerpts at all in wordpress? I want to remove excerpts completely for all posts? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` From the loop of blog or archive page.

Comment: No need to use `echo` the_excerpt()` echos the content.